# Icon overlay in windows not reflecting in explorer

Tags: python, windows, explorer, py2exe, shell-icons

I m using python2.7 and py2exe to create dll from my python script.

Successfully created a DLL and registered an entry for my icon overlay status and then restarted  windows explorer process through task manager.

Verified whether my entry is in registry and Yes, it was there.

But when i set my status through a python test app script for a specific folder location.

I expected all the files and folders in the selected path should overlayed with my overlay icon.

But No, Icon overlay is not happening at all.

But when i m testing through python script for register entry(without creating DLL) and setting my icon overlay through my test app script.

Yes, Its working perfectly.

I am confused why it is not happening when tried with my DLL???

Below is my python script to register an status entry

```
import os
import win32traceutil
import pythoncom
import winerror
from win32com.shell import shell, shellcon
from multiprocessing.connection import Client

REG_PATH = r'Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Explorer\ShellIconOverlayIdentifiers'
REG_KEY  = "IconOverlayTest"

class IconOverlay:
    _reg_desc_       = 'Icon Overlay COM Server'
    _public_methods_ = ['GetOverlayInfo', 'GetPriority','IsMemberOf']
    _com_interfaces_ = [shell.IID_IShellIconOverlayIdentifier, pythoncom.IID_IDispatch]
    def __init__(self, *_args, **_kwargs):
        self._icon = None
        self._icon_id = None
        raise NotImplementedError
    def GetOverlayInfo(self):
        return self._icon, 0, shellcon.ISIOI_ICONFILE
    def GetPriority(self):
        return 0
    def IsMemberOf(self, path, _attrs):
        if is_member(path, self._icon_id):
            return winerror.S_OK
        return winerror.E_FAIL

class IconOverlay_test(IconOverlay):
    _reg_progid_     = 'a.TestServer1'
    _reg_clsid_      = '{8B19F050-8354-11E1-A0FE-5C260A5D15E4}'
    def __init__(self):
        self._icon = "C:\\Users\\Administrator\\mat\\icon_overlay\\icons\\1.ico"
        self._icon_id = 101 

classes =   [IconOverlay_test,]

def is_member(path, icon_id):
    try:
        conn = None
        conn = Client("\\\\.\\pipe\\test.listener", "AF_PIPE")
        conn.send(path)
        if conn.poll(3):
            reply   =   conn.recv()
            return reply == icon_id
    except Exception:
        pass
    finally:
        conn and conn.close()
    return False

def DllRegisterServer():
    print("Registering %s ......."%IconOverlay._reg_desc_)
    import winreg
    #winreg = _winreg
    for view in [winreg.KEY_WOW64_64KEY, winreg.KEY_WOW64_32KEY]:
        for cls in classes:
            with winreg.CreateKeyEx(winreg.HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE, r"%s\%s" %
                    (REG_PATH, cls._reg_progid_), 0,
                    winreg.KEY_ALL_ACCESS|view) as hkey:
                print("    %s"%cls)
                winreg.SetValueEx(hkey, None, 0, winreg.REG_SZ, cls._reg_clsid_)
    print("Registration complete: %s" % IconOverlay._reg_desc_)

def DllUnregisterServer():
    print("Unregistering %s ......."%IconOverlay._reg_desc_)
    import winreg
    #winreg = _winreg
    for view in [winreg.KEY_WOW64_64KEY, winreg.KEY_WOW64_32KEY]:
        for cls in classes:
            try:
                _key = winreg.DeleteKeyEx(winreg.HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE, r"%s\%s"
                        % (REG_PATH, cls._reg_progid_),
                        winreg.KEY_ALL_ACCESS|view)
            except WindowsError as err:
                if err.errno != 2:
                    raise
    print("Unregistration complete: %s" % IconOverlay._reg_desc_)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    from win32com.server import register
    register.UseCommandLine(*classes,
                            finalize_register = DllRegisterServer,
                            finalize_unregister = DllUnregisterServer)
```

Answer (score 0):

This is really painful to get working right, goodluck!

I believe windows will only allow 10 different icons to be registered and it will only work with the first 10 registered alphabetically. Do you already have 10 registered? It's quite easy to exceed 10 if you have dropbox, tortoise-svn etc. installed as each image counts as an entry. If that's the case try putting an underscore or a 0 before the name to make sure it gets priority, although it will mean another icon will lose out- I don't think there's a way around this.

Also sometimes windows doesn't know to refresh the status of the icon. Which version of windows are you running? Some are worse than others. I seem to remember XP isn't very good at this. There's some tricks to get it to update though, you can refresh the window through windows api, but it looks horrible and the whole of explorer flashes. A better way I found is to change the an attribute on the file. This is the trick I used:

```
import stat,os

file_att= os.stat(path)[0]
if file_att & stat.S_IWRITE:
    os.chmod(path,stat.S_IREAD)
    os.chmod(path,stat.S_IWRITE)
else:
    os.chmod(path,stat.S_IWRITE)
    os.chmod(path,stat.S_IREAD)
```

Comment: I m working in windows 7. i ensured my app entries are listed first in registry to get the priority. My issue is the same python scripts works well when tested as scripts and the same is converted into dll which are not functioning properly when tested. If u hint me some ideas where might be the loop hole which would be a great help for me achieve this. give me a sample which works well for you.